# Download PDF from POST Response using (httpRequest / RESTer ..)

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Rest controller implemented in java(SpringMVC) , and I send a post request to reveive a PDF file using HttpRequester Or RESTer (i'm working on ubuntu) , is there any way to download this PDF instead of receiving a byte response?
something like this :

> v� �}��
>   A��P�M�y����Z�%_��J�.z���r�B��:Y��C����}��u���#��

Comment: wget <the url> ?

Comment: this is violation of REST rules. POST is update (with 200 code only), GET is receive

Comment: Try set the content type in the RequestMapping annotation. @RequestMapping(produces = "application/pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/foo/bar")

Answer (score 0):

Set Your response's contentType and header as follow, then write to you `response.getOutputStream()`

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=pdfname.pdf;");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", size );
```